# Stuck in "Syncing files to device Chrome"

Tags: google-chrome, flutter, flutter-web

I use VS as my IDE.

I set all up for web development and the command `flutter doctor` doesn't state any errors.

When I run my project with Chrome as device, VS gets stuck in "Syncing files to device Chrome".

I also tried running my project through terminal with `flutter run -d chrome --verbose`, the strange thing that happens when I run that command is that it Syncs successfully all the files (at least that's what the – verbose states) but the browser doesn't show any content.

There aren't errors in the browser console and I have the latest version installed.

Comment: Could you post the `flutter doctor` summary as well as the settings out put of `flutter config` from the command line.

Comment: @AbhilashC The `flutter doctor`: https://i.imgur.com/fA7pdSj.png | The `flutter config`: https://i.imgur.com/bhL4fDk.png

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and the problem was my index.html file was not pointing to my home page because I've changed the file name. Go to your index.html file under the web folder and check whether the script src is pointing to the correct path of your main function.

```
 <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when an import of my widget was added like this at the top of my dart file: `import 'file:///xxxxxx'`.

Changed it to `import 'package:my_project/xxxxxxx'` and it solved the Chrome issue. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a kinda very late answer but in case you didn't figure out how to solve this, try to `flutter clean` on the project then run it on the release mode via `flutter run --release`.
This should solve the problem.